# During the invasion of SF in Dawn of the Planet of the Apes, was the tank shot a cost cutting measure?

Tags: dawn-of-the-planet-of-the-apes

In Dawn of the Planet of the Apes, around the 1h22m mark, there's a ~90 second shot where the camera is fixed on the edge of an armored vehicle. The turret of the vehicle takes up roughly 1/3 of the screen and we see various bits of action from this perspective over the course of the shot.

It's an interesting camera tactic, but it made me wonder if it was a cost-cutting measure. The scene features hundreds of CGI apes running around, fire, explosions, etc. It seemed odd to me to then suddenly have such a large portion of the screen reduced to just the body of this vehicle.

Are there any interviews or behind-the-scenes features that talk about this shot?

Comment: Every single time you see two characters talking to each other in a room, it's a cost-cutting measure. Every time one of them blacks out or becomes unconscious for ten seconds and all you can see is darkness is a cost-cutting measure. Filmmaking is full of these tricks to avoid showing the actual money on screen